# CORS issue, using webworker with blob

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, web-worker

I'm using a webworker with a javascript blob since I want to be able to minify the project:

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var res = elements.worker.toString();
                res = res.substr(res.indexOf("\n")+1,res.length-4-res.indexOf("\n"));
                console.log(res)
                var blob;
                try {
                    blob = new Blob([res], {type: 'application/javascript'});
                } catch (e) { // Backwards-compatibility
                    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
                    blob = new BlobBuilder();
                    blob.append(res);
                    blob = blob.getBlob();
                }
                load.workNode = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

In the browser i get CORS-error. Why does webworker demand CORS? I've checked carefully. The webworker is causing the CORS-error. Same error in both chrome and firefox.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

In the dev-environment I'm using node with browserfy. I tried to enable CORS there with the npm package 'cors';

```
var cors = require('cors');
var proxy = require('./proxy');

function browserSyncInit(baseDir, files, browser) {
  browser = browser === undefined ? 'default' : browser;

  var routes = null;
  if(baseDir === paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && baseDir.indexOf(paths.src) !== -1)) {
    routes = {
      '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
    };
  }

  browserSync.instance = browserSync.init(files, {
    startPath: '/',
    server: {
      baseDir: baseDir,
      middleware: [proxy, cors()],
      routes: routes
    },
    port: 4000,
    browser: browser
  });
}
```

No success. What can I do?

Comment: "In the browser i get CORS-error" — What does the error message say?

Comment: @Quentin, I have updated the question with the error message.

Comment: The error message says that you can't make crossOrigin request fron the `blob:` protocol... Sounds kinda weird, but a workaround would be to use a FileReader, convert your blob to a dataURI version and start your worker from this dataURI. According to the message, `data:` URI scheme is allowed to do such requests.

Comment: Ps: if it really works, you don't even need a Blob and a FileReader: just encode your script content (using encodeURIComponent) and create the URI by prepending `data:text/plain; encoding=utf8,` to the encoded string.

Comment: PPs: just tried on FF 50 and chrome 54 and both works with the `blob:` protocol...

Comment: @Kaiido, Maybe it's something the webworker is executing causing the problem?

Comment: @PerStröm, yes it's an XMLHttpRequest to an other domain. The error message says it. But I can't repro. Which browser are you using? Here is a fiddle which should reproduce your issue : https://jsfiddle.net/7zwy7nLw/

Answer (score -1):

You can use heroku app Cors Anywhere to get around Cross-Origin-Request Errors errors,
Haven't tested it for web-workers but worth a shot at trying.

https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com

Simply add the above Url to the begining of the Url that you are attempting to make the XMLHttpRequest to let me know if it works as i'm currently still learning Node & webworkers myself..

Answer (score -2):

Usually CORS request have a pre request which asks if the request is allowed. You need to specify this CORS request to be allowed on your destination web server domain request. Unless you haven't did this, the CORS request will not work. This is ssentially needed for those requests.

You do this by adding the CORS allowed headers. In nginx or apache you can do this by simply adding a .htaccess file to that destination folder. I guess there is an equivalent on node.js web server engine. Good luck!